# Showing up my custom post type in primary navigation

Tags: custom-post-types, navigation

I have 4 custom post types set up in my blog and video is one of them. I want the video archives page (archives-video.php) to shop up in my primary navigation.

how do I do this without writing a custom function?

Comment: Please define "primary navigation". Also: are you using a custom theme, or one from the theme repository?

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the Wordpress documentation for registering_post_type in the code you are registering your custom post type you should be able to add: 'show_in_nav_menus' => true, and that should allow your post type to show in navigation menus. Here's the documentation for the [register_post_type function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type)

Adding a link in your menu straight to the page also works, but in my opinion it is very messy. It would seem not many people are aware of the show_in_nav_menus argument of register_post_type because by default the value is set to false.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: For me at least, adding 'show_in_nav_menus' allows individual posts to be added to the menu, but doesn't give me an addable archive page, which is I believe what the asker was looking for

Answer (score 0):

In absence of further context from you, I would advise that you create a [WordPress menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_SubPanel) and simply add a link to your custom post type's archive page.

Comment: My 'primary' menu is a natively created wordpress menu, zamoose. and since its automated, I can't add a link manually correct?

Answer (score 0):

Amit,

WordPress (3.2) does not currently provide a way for you to add custom post type archive page into the navigation.  One way to do it would to create a page with a slug that matches the slug of your post type archive page. This page will just be a placeholder so the archive page shows up in your navigation.

For example, if, when registering your video CPT, you set has_archive => 'videos', create a page called 'Videos'.

Videos will now show up in your navigation and when /videos/ is requested, users will get the videos CPT archive page and not the Videos page because of the order of the rewrite rules that WordPress creates.